# add seconds in float and int type to date

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a list of seconds including float and integers types. When I add the seconds in int type, my code works but in the case of float, it gives me the following error,

**"TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: Timestamp"**

For example, it works for 0 and 5 but it doesn't for 3.14 seconds.
Would you please have any suggestions to solve this problem?

thank you very much

**Here is my code**

```
first_day = df.iloc[1, 0][0:8] 
date = datetime.strptime(first_day, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
with open('myfile.txt','w') as f:
for i in range(len(df)):
    itp = df.iloc[5, 1].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    if itp != '':
        P=int(float(itp))/100
    else:
        P=0
        print(P)
        type(P)
    #P_sec=itp/100
        P= pd.to_datetime(date) + pd.DateOffset(seconds=30)
        t2=pd.to_datetime(date) + pd.DateOffset(seconds=P)
        date=pd.to_datetime(t1) - pd.DateOffset(seconds=15)
        print(date,P,t2,file = f)
```

Comment: Style suggestion: streamline `df.iloc[5, 1].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')` using regular expressions: `re.sub(r"[\[\]]", "", df.iloc[5, 1])`.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the comment. it gave the same output but the problem still exists. If P is int type, code works but not in case of float.

Comment: I'm not awake enough to make it work right now, but I can help you improve your code in other ways.

Comment: @Chris Oh sorry I found a bug in the code. I should not use the same variable for two different outputs. P is used two times in the above code.